# Is a Kohen Allowed to Receive an Organ Donation?

Tags: kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

A Kohen is forbidden from becoming *Tamei Meis* (coming in contact with a dead body) (Vayikra-21)

**Aside from being allowed for *Pikuach Nefesh* reasons** (life threatening situation). What other reasons can be found to allow a Kohen to receive an organ donation from a deceased person?

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71481/unclean-due-to-an-organ-transplant-in-the-context-of-the-rebuilt-temple

Comment: is organ tissue like that actually dead tissue yet?

Comment: @DexStakker: Indeed it is not. Transplanting dead tissue defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoted from the book [Healing in Halacha By Rabbi Micha Cohn](http://mosaicapress.com/healing-in-halacha/) (page. 245-247 Mosaica Press 2016)

> Rav Moshe Feinstein (Iggros Moshe Yoreh Deah 1:230), wrote on the
>   opinions of a contemporary Rabbi Yitzchok Isaac Leibes, who wrote a
>   Kuntres called Rofe Kol Bassar where he asks this very question.
>
> One of the issues that Rabbi Leibes and Rabbi Feinstein discussed was
>   our question about the permissibility of a Kohen to receive an organ
>   transplant. Rabbi Leibes pointed out that if the size of the tissue
>   being transplanted is more than an olive, it could give off tumah
>   ritual impurity, and a Kohen would be prohibited from coming in
>   contact with it even in today's times. Rabbi Leibes offered a number
>   of possible arguments to permit a Kohen to accept a transplant, such
>   as relying on less mainstream opinions that maintain that there is not
>   a Torah prohibition for a Kohen to defile himself in contemporary
>   times when he is already ritually impure, as well as the opinion of
>   the Maharashdam that questions the reliability of a Kohen's tradition
>   on his lineage. Rabbi Feinstein did not view these reasons as being
>   substantial, and offered a perspective of his own
>
> Firstly, Rabbi Feinstein pointed out that if the tissue will be put
>   inside the body, there is a concept of tumah balu'ah that ritual
>   impurity is not transferred from inside the body. The commentary of
>   Rabbeinu Shimshon explains that since it is inside the body, it loses
>   its own significance and is considered a part of the body. Based on
>   this idea, if the tissue is transplanted Based on will beneath the
>   skin, the patient not become tamei since it is not in contact with
>   external part of the the recipient's body. This would be a significant
>   argument to permit a Kohen to receive a transplant since most
>   transplanted organs ar visible externally.
>
> Furthermore, the Rambam writes that although human skin from a
>   deceased person is ritually impure, if it is chemically treated it
>   lose its tumah. The reason seems to be because when an item takes on a
>   new form, it loses its previous status. Based on this concept, Rabbi
>   Feinstein understands that if tissue from the deceased takes on a new
>   role, like being used in a transplant, it removes the tumah status
>   from it. **As such, a Kohen would be allowed to a accept a transplant**
>   (given certain provisions) even if it is not beneath the skin, the
>   very fact that it is now part of a living person gives it a new status
>   and removes the tumah.

Answer (score 1):

The shach in Yoreh Deah 157:1 questions whether the risk of losing a limb is reason enough to allow transgression of a *lo-taaseh*.
He concludes that it is permissible. [Shabbos or other kares may be an exception]

[See also ריב”ש סי’ יו"ד שפ”ז ובאו”ח סימן שכ”ח סי”ז. בפרי מגדים שם סי’ שכח במשב”ז , חוות יאיר סי’ קפג, שו”ת אבני נזר או”ח קלג, ובשו”ת אגרות משה יו”ד ב’ סי’ קעד ענף ד’.]

Thus even if the organ still retained its tumah, the kohen would be permitted to receive the transplant, since this is not worse than saving an organ at risk.