# Receiving animal based organ transplants

Tags: animals, medicine, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

I was looking at the idea of receiving an organ transplanted from an animal as in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71473/acceptable-to-receive-transplant-of-organs-grown-inside-pigs/71520#71520) question. One issue which was not raised is that of tum'ah. Though the transplant might be acceptable for many reasons, might it have a long term implication?

If touching the carcass of a dead animal (at least before it is all [dried](https://www.tabletmag.com/sections/belief/articles/daf-yomi-144-tamei-kirsch) out) confers some level of impurity (just until the [evening](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifra%2C_Tazria_Parashat_Nega%27im%2C_Section_5.1?lang=bi&with=Mishnah&lang2=en)?), wouldn't the recipient of an animal heart be constantly impure because his body is in constant contact with the transplanted organ? Wouldn't this mean that he can't ever be involved in the korbanot of a Yom Tov at the Beit Hamikdash?

Comment: טומאת בית הסתרים

Comment: so should I wait until they perfect transplanting monkey fingers onto humans to ask again?

Comment: @JoelK מגע בית הסתרים or טומאה בלועה https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D

Comment: @joel K Currently, for severe burn victims, they sometimes use pig flesh. That’s in the open and the question applies

Comment: The my Jewish Learning link in the answer on the question you linked to, seems to say that there would be a problem of tumah. (Not sure if it’s an issue that’s discussed, since it’s something Moshiach can determine